# Combining a neural network and hidden Markov models

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, hidden-markov-models

I am reading a paper where authors use neural networks to produce emission and transition probabilities. And I am confused about the way they've described their emission architecture and transition architecture in section 4.1 'Producing probabilties'.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1609.09007.pdf

For example, if I have a protein sequence which could be made of 20 different letters and each letter in that sequence has an underlying state. And there are three underlying states (S,B,C) in total. Then for emission architecture, what will my tag vector (v_i) look like and what will my vector embedding look like (w_i)? I would appreciate if someone could explain it in terms of this biological problem because it'll be easier for me to understand this way.

Comment: Where is page 66 there?

Comment: My apologies. It's weird it doesn't show page number on web browser. Anyway Can you look at section 4.1 'Producing probabilities'. Underneath that section you can see emission architecture and transition architecture.

Comment: Not a *programming* question, hence arguably off-topic here; better suited for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).